# Criando link de pesquisa?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ajax

Tenho um problema em um projeto, existem 3 campos de pesquisa de produto e um botão pesquisar.

exemplo:  https://jsfiddle.net/juliomoreira666/u3ss4uye/

Queria que conforme os campos fossem sendo preenchidos, o botão pesquisar carregasse o link construido.

Exemplo: São 3 campos então ficariam assim / www.rs1.com.br/valor1/valor2/valor3

existe essa possibilidade ?

Desde já agradeço amigos!

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a funcionalidade que pretendes? Isso é para usar numa querystring? ou para ir para urls diferentes? existe uma form?

Comment: Ainda acho que valia a pena responderes à minha pergunta em cima ^ (mesmo depois de teres aceito uma resposta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode montar o link de acordo com o conteúdo dos campos com javascript.

Não sei se seria a melhor opção, mas dá certo.

Faça o teste.

```html
<div class="container">
    <input id="montadora" type="text" value="montadora"></input>
    <input id="modelo" type="text" value="modelo"></input>
    <input id="ano" type="text" value="ano"></input>
    <INPUT type="reset"  name="b2" value="Limpar">
    <INPUT type="submit" name="b1" value="Pesquisar" onClick="location.href='http://www.rs1.com.br/'+document.getElementById('montadora').value+'/'+document.getElementById('modelo').value+'/'+document.getElementById('ano').value">
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi Fabiano, irei fazer os testes, mais agradeço desde já a ajuda! ;)

Comment: Se gostar avalie a resposta. Valeu